# Add Vue main component in layout with params from backend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a single page application with vue 3 and backend on php. When I render start page from php I want to send some parameters to the vue main template by this way:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <my-app :params="{{params}}" />
  </div>
  <script src="/public/assets/dist/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
  <script src="/public/assets/dist/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

chunk-vendors.js and app.js are generated by vue-cli-service build command.
But it doesn't work like this, so I have to send them in separete script section as global variable:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <script>
      $_data = JSON.parse('{{data}}')
  </script>
  <script src="/public/assets/dist/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
  <script src="/public/assets/dist/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now my initial vue script main.js looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App'

const app = createApp({})

app.component('my-app', App)

app.mount('#app')
```

I also tried to make it like web component by vue-cli-service build --target wc but in this case there is an error:
Vue 3 support of the web component target is still under development.

Is it possible to do it as I wrote above?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode production --modern --name app",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --mode production --modern --name app --watch",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  outputDir: '../../public/assets/dist/',
  filenameHashing: false
})
```

Comment: It's unclear what's the problem. Both are workable, as long as {{ }} is interpolated correctly on server side. Vue 3 doesn't have the support for WC output but it's not needed for this task

Comment: Now it works only if I do like this:

    const app = createApp(App)

But in this case I dont have a possability to create a template with props in main html file, all logic works only inside App.vue.

Comment: That's correct. It's either using createApp({}) AND <my-app> to pass through props, or  createApp(App) directly. Any way, passing data through a global like $_data is a common and framework-independent approach. You can use provide/inject to pass data from App to the rest of the app with both of them

Comment: I think that passing data through <my-app> would be more preferred way in vue. But I really don't understand why it doesn't work in my case(

Comment: <my-app> won't work with Vue build with stripped compiler, so it's less desirable. Consider providing a way to reproduce the problem. It should work, at least if {{params}} is correctly formatted JS object

Comment: How I can know what compiler type I have? I've also add my package.json and vue.config.js in issue description if it can help.

Comment: I can't say if it's the case because the question doesn't explain what's wrong with code. See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding . Any way, not including a compiler is the right choice because "preferred way in vue" shouldn't be the reason to add extra footprint to the app